# How do I get a tight fit around a node when using tikz shapes.geometric?

Tags: tikz-pgf, bounding-box, shapes

I would like the two nodes below to be roughly the same size, but one is much larger than the other.  Is there a way to force tikz to reconsider its bounding box calculation?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{
  positioning,
  shapes.geometric
}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\gpi}{\mathrm{GPi}}
\newcommand{\gpep}{\mathrm{GPe_{+}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=9mm, shape=regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6] (gpi)  {$\gpi$};
    \node[draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=9mm, shape=regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6] (gpep) [left=40mm of gpi] {$\gpep$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Measure the width of the plus subscript with `\settowidth` and add an empty box before and an empty box after the text in the right node. Each empty box should have a width that is half the size of the plus subscript. (I'm assuming you want the text centred:-)

Comment: Choose a larger value as `minimum size`...

Comment: @MarcvanDongen  Thank you. Is there no way to make the left node smaller?

Comment: It would look ugly IMO. changing `inner sep` as suggested by @PaulGaborit and suggested below is probably easier than the suggestion I suggested but you should be careful when the type size changes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I enclose an example where text in the left hexagon is not affecting the width of node. The width can be set by other means.

```
%! *latex mal-shapes.tex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\gpi}{\mathrm{GPi}}
\newcommand{\gpep}{\makebox[0pt][c]{$\mathrm{GPe_{+}}$}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm, shape=regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6] (gpi)  {$\gpi$};
    \node[draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm, shape=regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6] (gpep) [left=5mm of gpi] {\gpep};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility would be to fix shape size with `\phantom{$\gpi$}` and add real text with `label=center:$\gpep$` option.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{
  positioning,
  shapes.geometric
}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\gpi}{\mathrm{GPi}}
\newcommand{\gpep}{\mathrm{GPe_{+}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=9mm, 
          shape=regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6] (gpi) {$\gpi$};
    \node[draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=9mm, 
         shape=regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, 
         label=center:$\gpep$] (gpep) [left=10mm of gpi] {\phantom{$\gpi$}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For this shape at least, the `inner sep` can be negative without serious consequences (although I guess this is an unintended feature).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6}]
\node [inner sep=-10mm, minimum size=10mm, draw] at (-1,0) {GPe$_+$};
\node [inner sep=-10mm, minimum size=10mm, draw] at ( 1,0) {GPi};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]